# De-normalizing data into a code first Entity Framework entity, without a SQL View

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

First, here's a simple example database model, which has `Products` assigned to `Categories`, where `CategoryId` in `Products` is the FK relationship to `Categories`.

**Products**:

- ProductId (PK), INT
- ProductName VARCHAR(255)
- CategoryId (FK), INT

**Categories**

- CategoryId (PK), INT
- CategoryName VARCHAR(255)

For the .NET application data model, only a de-normalized representation of a `Product` is defined as an entity class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

There is no `Category` class defined, and for this example, none is planned.

In the code-first Entity Framework `DbContext`-derived class, I've setup the `DbSet<Product> Products` entity set:

```
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

And in the `EntityTypeConfiguration`, I'm attempting to wire it up, but I'm just not able to get it working right:

```
public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.ProductId);

        // How do I instruct EF to pull just the column 'CategoryName'
        // from the FK-related Categories table?
    }
}
```

I realize that a SQL View could be created and then I could tell EF to map to that view using `ToTable("App1ProductsView")`, but in this example, I'd like to avoid doing so.

In a SQL ADO.NET ORM solution, there's no issue here. I can simply write my own SQL statement to perform the `INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.CategoryId = p.CategoryId` join. How can I use the EF code-first Fluent API to perform this same inner join when populating the entity?

In my research, I've seen a lot of "entity split across multiple tables" topics, but this is not that. Categories and Products are two distinct entities (from a database perspective), but the .NET code is meant to stay unaware of that.

**Failed Attempt 1**:

This does not work, and produces a strange query (seen with SQL Server Profiler).

Fluent config:

```
Map(m =>
{
    m.Property(t => t.CategoryName);
    m.ToTable("Categories");
});
```

Resulting SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
    [Extent2].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent2].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
FROM  [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Product1] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[ProductId]
```

Comment: Why would you want to? It’s an ORM that means it needs an object to map to and from. Sound like you really want more control over your domain level objects, in that case simply use a separate set of objects for your domain and another for your datalayer and use a tool like automapper

Comment: You are correct. In this example, the domain objects are expected to be more closely bound to the ORM backend, eliminating the additional layer of ORM-only entities and the subsequent mapping between the two layers. I appreciate your insight of moving towards a true DDD approach. As the current design decision is debatable, I'll digress. I'm merely hoping an EF expert could speak to the EF Fluent API, and whether or not this is possible, without creating what amounts to a "domain-entity-specific SQL view" on the ORM side. Technically, it seems feasible, only that I'm missing something...

Comment: Take a look at Enity Splitting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx

Comment: You describe this like the design is set in stone. Why can't you simply map the Product and Category classes and project them to this custom `Product` class you' show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: MS EF6 is not designed for that, you can't do it easily.

Please read about the [keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#key), 
[relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) and how to [configure one-to-many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-relationship-where-both-ends-are-required-one-to-one).

EF expects your entity to have a key which is a part of a mapped table.
You could use splitting, i.e. put some properties in Table1 and some to Table2, but *only* if both tables share the same primary key.
That works for [1] -> [0..1] relationships only. What you have is a one-to-many.

EF way of mapping your db schema *is* to create two entities and access the category name as `Product.Category.Name`.

If you completely do not want to expose *Category* entity, you may use an internal class and a protected property, exposing category name as a [sql-ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties#specifying-not-to-map-a-clr-property-to-a-column-in-the-database) property `public string CategoryName => this.Category?.Name`.

The other option is to use [untracked SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql#writing-sql-queries-for-non-entity-types). 
Then you will have to write SQL query yourself, as you did for the pure ADO.NET solution.

If you don't want to use EF change tracking, relationships and etc, consider a lighter ORM like Dapper, linq2db or BLToolkit.

Comment: Direct SQL queries in EF is an option, and after we evaluated that approach, we found it would mean writing a lot of SQL anyways, and EF is merely serving a mapping API. NHibernate behaved the same way (which makes sense -- NH is near to EF). We looked at Dapper for just mapping as well. In the end, we're going to stick with ADO for now, and directly map to our Domain Models in our Repositories, for performance and layer reduction. If we see that growing wild, we always have the option to push out the ORM into something "real" (true ORM--with 1 entity/table) and then map in the Repositories.

Comment: Can you do this with EF Core

Comment: Update! We are over two years into our pattern, half of that in production, and it has been fairly successful for us. There have been some nice optimizations we were able to do in order to get queries super speedy that would not have been possible with a rigid ORM layer. Using a generic repository design, whose implementations sit directly on top of SQL, we've managed to maintain our pattern without fail. There are some fairly complex architectural components I wrote that make it easier to use, but aren't truly necessary. I'm hopeful I can write about this pattern one day, maybe github it.

Comment: Correct answer, but I wonder WHY. It supports lazy-loading the relations, so one would think it might be pretty easy to create a multi-statement batch and deal with the mapping as they would if they were lazy-loaded. Include as it works might more often create catastrophic performance rather than be an optimization, and it just seems like that is completely unneccesary. I'm probably missing something, but I'd like to understand what makes this so hard to do.